# Background Running Program: nohup python script.py & ... Sufficient for perminant running?

Tags: python, shell, background, nohup

On my server I'm setting up a python script to run in the background:

```
nohup python script.py &
```

Seems simple enough, but it seems that it fizzled somewhere. I was wondering if I must run it as a root user to establish it's permanence?

I'm on a dedicated server, so I'm not aware I have any limitations.

Comment: That's correct. It probably end because of an error in your script

Comment: Thanks -- I figured as much :(

Comment: I guess instead of nohup I should be using nohickup

Comment: Check that your provider allow long running process but this should not be an issue on a dedicated server. Alternatively you can try to catch the error with something like: try: main(); except Exception as e: open('log', 'w').write(e)

Comment: another nice method to run anything in the background is `screen` or `tmux`. They provide a shell that can be detached from the terminal (Ctrl-a d for screen) and can be reattached with `screen -r`. If your script should run all the time you should think about using an init script though